# How to stop Google Webmaster Tools from emailing me about a removed domain?

Tags: google, domains, google-search-console

I have an old site that I used to manage through Google Webmaster Tools, which I have since abandoned (took down website and no longer own the domain).

I deleted the site from my webmaster tools page, and yet I still get emails from Google saying that "Google can't reach your site at www.mydomain.com".

How can I stop this?

Comment: That's a good one. I wish I knew. I will have to think on this a bit.

Comment: You could try adding it and then deleting it again.

Comment: How long has it been since you deleted the site in GWT?

Comment: @Wexford I have done that, to no avail!

Comment: @w3d Months since I've deleted. As mentioned I've also re-added and deleted, and that was months ago as well

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you deleted the site from the main Webmaster Tools page without first unverifying yourself as a user/owner of the site. (Although you would perhaps expect the current account to be unverified automatically - that does not seem to be the case.)

However, you should still be able to visit [Webmaster Central - Verification Home](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home) from where you can manage your *verified* sites.

Comment: I was really hoping this would be the case, but the site does not show up in my verified domains

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like somewhere there is perhaps a glitch in Google's systems that is not recognising the fact you deleted the site from your Webmasters account. I would suggest posting on their [Webmaster Help Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/webmasters/crawling-indexing--ranking) to see if they can help you from there. This is their recommended route for reporting non-standard issues.